# <stddef.h> not found when running a standalone clang tool on .cpp file

Tags: c++, clang

I was trying to run the standalone tool(ASTFrontend--the binary file) that I built on the following c++ code(tou.cpp). This tool will detect the location of the all the functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello,world!";
  return 0;
}
```

I ran the following command 
`./ASTFrontend ../../sampleCode/tou.cpp` 
and I got the following error:

```
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "../../sampleCode/tou.cpp"
No compilation database found in /home/parallels/PierceProject/ASTParser/build/../../sampleCode or any parent directory
fixed-compilation-database: Error while opening fixed database: No such file or directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
In file included from /home/parallels/PierceProject/ASTParser/build/../../sampleCode/tou.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/ios:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/iosfwd:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/bits/postypes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/cwchar:44:
/usr/include/wchar.h:35:10: fatal error: 'stddef.h' file not found
#include <stddef.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I've read about other related questions, but none of them helped. 
Ideally, the out supposed to look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// Found function main returning int
int main()
{
  cout<<"Hello,world!";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You  haven't  specified  what your compile command line is nor what you're trying to accomplish. If you're just trying to compile,  your code is fine, just run clang++ with only the filename as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited it.

Comment: You have to compile your code with the proper clang arguments to generate the database.  See https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/compilation-database.html#what-is-a-compilation-database

Comment: In fact, that header file can be found at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/`, now I just need to find a way to tell the preprocessor to locate it correctly. I don't know why it came up with `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/cwchar:44` such a twisted way to search headers though

Answer (score 0):

my stddef is simply found in “/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/include/”. By adding extra flag to my tool, error disappears: ./bin/clang-zz ../../src/test1230.cpp  -- -I/home/zz/workspace/vcast/include/ -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.5.0/include/